# How to insert into Binary Search Tree

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, binary-search-tree

I am trying to insert into a Binary Search Tree everything compiles but when I try to run the program I get `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` everything looks good to me and I can't find the issue. Please Help.

```
int main()
{
struct node
{
  int item;
  node *left;
  node *right;
};

node * root = NULL;
int x = 9;

void BinarySearchTree::insert(x)
{
   insert(x, root);
}

void insert(x, node *t)
{

    if(t == NULL)
    {
        t-> item = x;   
        t->left = NULL;
        t->right = NULL;
    }

    else if(x < t-> item)
    {
        insert(x, t->left);
    }
    else if(t->item < x)
    {
        insert(x, t->right);
    }
    else
    {
    ;//do nothing
    }
} 
}
```

Comment: How do you run it? Where is your main function?

Comment: forgot to add that part in.

Comment: That code doesn't even compile for so many reasons. Please post your real code or an MCVE.

Answer (score 3):

If the pointer is null, then you try to indirect through it to set the values of the non-existent node. That will cause your segfault.

You probably want to take the argument by reference, so you can update it to point to a new node if necessary:

```
void insert(x, node *&t)
{  //                ^
    if (t == nullptr) {
        t = new node {x, nullptr, nullptr};
    }
    // the rest of the function should work as it is
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is incomplete, and without context it becomes difficult to answer accurately. That being said, there is something in the code that seems unhealthy.

the

```
void insert(x, node *t){}
```

function takes a value, and a pointer to an allocated structure.
if you hand it a *null* value, instead of a pointer to an allocated structure, your code will attempt to assign a value to **null->item** which is still *null*. So this will give you a segmentation fault.

```
if(t == NULL)
{
    t-> item = x;   
    t->left = NULL;
    t->right = NULL;
}
```

You must decide what to do, when not handed a a pointer to a previously allocated  structure.

either, throw exception, or automatically create a new object (allocate the structure), and then assign the value.

notice if you do the latter, that you will need to return the address, of the pointer, or change the parameter to become a reference to a pointer...